# JupyterLab ipywidget close one widget and display another on button click

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I'm new to Jupyterlab and ipywidget (and might be missing some fundamentals).

This seems to be simple, but I searched everywhere and could not find a way to do this.

I just need to close widget A and display widget B on button click event (of widget A).

This is what I have tried/need in simple terms.

```
import ipywidgets
from IPython.display import display

buttonA_widget = ipywidgets.Button(description='Button A')
buttonB_widget = ipywidgets.Button(description='Button B')

display(buttonA_widget)

def switchMode(x):
    buttonA_widget.close()
    display(buttonB_widget)

buttonA_widget.on_click(switchMode)
```

When I tried above, buttonA get disappear, but second display call does not get executed

and I don't get any error messages (trying this on Jetson Nano).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the button in an `Output` widget and clear it when required:

```py
import ipywidgets
from IPython.display import display

buttonA_widget = ipywidgets.Button(description='Button A')
buttonB_widget = ipywidgets.Button(description='Button B')

out = ipywidgets.Output()

with out:
    display(buttonA_widget)


def switchMode(x):
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
        display(buttonB_widget)


buttonA_widget.on_click(switchMode)
out
```